# Unknown Error after building dlib for c++ properly, while importing it

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dlib

Hi after successfully building dlib for c++ flowing this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKGkA_K1KPA&list=WL&index=2&t=148s

I created the Debug part of it and then created my cpp file with just this line:

`#include <dlib/image_processing.h>`

on running it, I got this error..
Can someone pls help...

```
1>Test.cpp
1>C:\dlib-19.6\source\dlib\console_progress_indicator.h(153,28): warning C4834: discarding return value of function with 'nodiscard' attribute
1>C:\dlib-19.6\source\dlib\serialize.h(527,17): warning C4834: discarding return value of function with 'nodiscard' attribute
1>C:\dlib-19.6\source\dlib\serialize.h(587): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool dlib::old_deserialize_floating_point<T>(T &,std::istream &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=float
1>        ]
1>C:\dlib-19.6\source\dlib\serialize.h(599): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void dlib::deserialize_floating_point<float>(T &,std::istream &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=float
1>        ]
1>Test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives
1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
1>D:\roboatics\open_cv_facial recognition\try5\try5\x64\Debug\try5.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "try5.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am having no clue what to do... pls help

Comment: Looks like you were supposed to use CMake to generate a project for msvc and compile that to build dlib: [https://github.com/davisking/dlib](https://github.com/davisking/dlib)

Comment: BTW. linking to a tutorial video does not really help your question as very few people will invest the time to watch the video to attempt to figure out what you did. You should instead explain the steps you took.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol   USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives`

I'm guessing that there's some tricks in the library to generate an error message whose symbol name reads as the desired error string, which is "missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file *OR* inconsistent use of DEBUG or ENABLE ASSERTS preprocessor directives"

My first guess is that your CPP file doesn't use the same Debug or Asserts configuration as the library you are linking with.

---

The error about missing `main` is because, as you said, your CPP file included only the one line, which means your program does not have a `main` function defined.  You can see that this error is coming from the standard library, not your `dlib`.

Comment: My guess is the first error may indicate you are linking with a Release compiled library in debug mode and the makers of dlib took steps to prevent you from UB caused by this.

Comment: @drescherjm Using MSVC, the debug and release builds by convention don't have different names (a -d suffix) but rather use different directories.  Setting the project options to Debug or Release takes care of that automatically, so that's not a common mistake to make at all, unless manually naming libraries in the advanced options.

Comment: However, the stand-alone library may have options that are configured in its own build, that were not duplicated in the Project that uses the library.  That _would_ be an easy thing to miss.

Comment: What I am saying is if the user manually added the linker input for the third party library to their own project. I have seen new users add the release version to all configurations thinking they don't need to debug the library.

Comment: Yea, I guess when he said  he "followed the instructions" and see that he's using a `.vcxproj` invoked via the IDE, I assume the instructions are to add the library's project as a reference.  But we don't really know what he did...

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for the help.. I will share link of new question which includes complete details ... pls help I really need your support :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69139588/issue-in-facial-recognition-project-using-c